# Node.js Express framework: can't get CSS file

Tags: css, node.js, express

I want to access my .html with localhost via node.js.
I use the express framework for this. My .html contains some CSS, but this doesn't get loaded with the html file.

**Code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('FrontPage.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening to 3000");
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/FrontPageCSS.css">
</head>



<body style="background-image:url(./img/bg.jpg)">

<div id="header">
        <a href="./frontPage.html"><img src="./img/Logo.png" height="5%" width="5%" alt="logo"></a>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./script/FrontPageJS.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="buttonWrapper">
    <div id="first" class="first">
        This is my first button
    </div>

    <div id="second" class="second">
        This is my second button
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#header{
    text-align: center;
}
div#buttonWrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
div.madeBefore, div.madeNotBefore{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ffc300 , #ff8300);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffc300, #ff8300);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffc300, #ff8300);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffc300 , #ff8300);
    width: 500px;
    height: 425px;
    margin-right: 50px;

    padding:50px;
    padding-top: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0,       0, 0.2);
    color: #B36103;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.madeNotBefore{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
div.madeBefore:hover, div.madeNotBefore:hover{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ff7600 , #e96c00);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7600, #e96c00);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7600, #e96c00);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff7600 , #e96c00);
}
```

How do I make sure the CSS gets sended togheter with the .html?

Comment: Show your html and css please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your css content is inside your public folder. For example if you have a folder **css** inside **public** folder and your css file is named **FrontPageCSS.css** then you can use it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/FrontPageCSS.css">
```

You can asume that you are inside **public** for references.

Answer (score 6):

Add this:

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

create folder public, put css files inside and in your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/FrontPageCSS.css" />
```

Comment: I still only get the html without any CSS.

Comment: Open your browser then go to the console (ctrl + shift + j in chrome) and look at "Console tab" Do you have any errors? Problem with load css?

Comment: Yes, it indeed gives me: failed to load resources. The path it gives me is still my old path instead of the new one with public/..

Comment: Try hard refresh Ctrl + F5?

Comment: Doesn't work either. I don't no why it still talks about the previous path in the error while I changed it in my html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96913/discussion-between-klijakub-and-stijn).

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything:

1) Verify that public/ is in the main folder of the server. (So wherever your server file is, public/ should in that same directory)

2) ...verify the css file is actually there.

Then, use this to make the /public directory static:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And in your file, set this to get your CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/FrontPageCSS.css">
```